# Gulp giving a lot of syntax/lint errors when I run it. Why?

Tags: reactjs, gulp, webpack, lint, eslint

This may not even be Gulp thing. It may be something with a Webpack config I fear or possibly my linting setup.  Im thinking there must be a proper ES or TS Lint I need to tie into Gulp so when it builds my client and server generated Js files for the this React Asp.net Core app it will not be so picking.  I'm in Visual Studio Code and normally simply right clicking and formating the document will take care of little issues like this but when I run gulp, it goes crazy on this new project.  This are little errors that seems over picky to me regarding spacing and what not.  Anyone have any experience with this?

```
9:18  error    A space is required after '{'             object-curly-spacing    
9:28  error    A space is required before '}'             object-curly-spacing   
14:1   error    Trailing spaces not allowed             no-trailing-spaces

  9:18  error    A space is required after '{'             object-curly-spacing    
9:28  error    A space is required before '}'             object-curly-spacing   
14:1   error    Trailing spaces not allowed             no-trailing-spaces     
15:3   error    handleChange should be placed after componentDidMount             react/sort-comp
```

Here is an example of what this sample of the errors is coming from.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';
// import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
     this.state = {value: ''};

     this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
     this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
      this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
      alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
      event.preventDefault();
    }

 componentDidMount() { }
 render() {
return (
  <div>
    <Helmet title="Test" />
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <label>
    Name:
    <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </div>
);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Without the code that is raising the error, it's hard to help. Could you include the the problematic part in the question?

Comment: Your linter is configured with style rules that don't match the way you're formatting your code.  Either change your code style or reconfigure the linter to remove the rules "object-curly-spacing" and "no-trailing-spaces".

Comment: @Aurora0001, i added the code.  Let me know if you see anything.  Thanks.

Comment: @DanielBeck whenever i've googled this it does lead me to believe i may need to configure my eslint plugin to deal with this stuff.  I just thought maybe in my case it was Gulp or maybe something with Webpack.

Comment: Gulp and webpack are just tool runners; they'll run whatever tools you ask them to. Including, in this case, ESLint.

Comment: Go to http://eslint.org/docs/rules/ and find what rules you actually want to include and change your eslint config file accordingly http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring. If you have not defined the config file you will get a stricter linter. Additionally, a TS linter accommodates other options than the ones in the link above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the constructive comments, i was able to better understand my eslinter configuration.  The rules were in fact maybe a little to sensitive for my needs in this case.  I changed my rules so they wouldn't blow up generating my client and server js files using Gulp.  This is all pretty new to me.  Im not sure why the right click format isn't taking care of most of these issues for me in Visual Studio code.  I have the latest eslint plug installed so I would think it should be up to date.  here are the current rules in my .eslintrc file.

```
"rules": {
"comma-dangle": 0,  // not sure why airbnb turned this on. gross!
"indent": 0,
"object-curly-spacing": 0,
"no-trailing-spaces": 0,
"react/prefer-stateless-function": 0,
"react/prop-types": 0,
"react/jsx-closing-bracket-location": 0,
"react/jsx-indent": 0,
"no-console": 0,
"prefer-template": 0,
"max-len": 0,
"no-underscore-dangle": [2, {"allow": ["__data"]}],
"global-require": 0,
"no-restricted-syntax": 0,
"linebreak-style": 0,
"react/jsx-filename-extension": 0,
"import/imports-first": 0
},
```

Thanks @Daniel Beck and @CriCri